# outlook web app getAccessTokenAsync in Outlook 2016

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

I am currently trying to get a sample web addin for outlook to work in owa and outlook 2016 desktop.

I am able to get the access token in OWA but the auth object in Office.context.auth is always undefined.

What is the problem??

I have used the getCallBackTokenAsync as well but i am unable to.

Can somebody help me please??

Comment: Can you check if office.initialize is being called before checking the Office.context.auth value? To be able to help you better, can you share the scenario you want to achieve using the auth token in your addin?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook for Windows and Web, I use `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync();`.

As I never tried to apply this to OWA I don't know what it will be like in that.